# How to create snippetID for all the processors,processgroups in the Entire UI using restapi in c#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, apache-nifi

I am creating a template in nifi. For that I am trying to create a snippet using rest api "/snippets" (POST) in c#. I need to create a snippet with multiple processors,multiple process groups,multiple input ports etc. And moreover the name and id of the processors or process groups remains same in the json and how to set the value for it ? Here is my json data :

```
{
    "snippet": {
        "parentGroupId": "a99f64f4-0158-1000-f989-c1d4fd2d069e",
        "processGroups": {
            "2b76344b-0159-1000-d64e-d9f10b8f696a": {
                "clientId":"2b76344b-0159-1000-d64e-d9f10b8f696a",
                "version": 0,
                "lastModifier": "value"

            }
        },
        "processors":{
            "2b75e2a1-0159-1000-38d2-e93cd0c3dd7b": {
                "clientId": "2b75e2a1-0159-1000-38d2-e93cd0c3dd7b",
                "version": 0,
                "lastModifier": "value"

        },
        "5d91382f-0159-1000-ca54-7a0f4d639e4c": {
                "clientId": "5d91382f-0159-1000-ca54-7a0f4d639e4c",
                "version": 0,
                "lastModifier": "value"

        }
        }


    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the behavior you're seeing? After quickly glancing, I think your JSON looks correct.